# After updating my Mac OS to Catalina, Flutter is not working anymore in Android Studio. I deleted and re-installed, but still not working

Tags: bash, flutter, macos-catalina

Please Please help. After updating the OS to Catalina, Android Studio would still open, but none of my Flutter apps will work and the emulators do not open (they say 'Loading')
I unistalled Flutter and re-installed it, but in the Terminal when I type in flutter doctor -v, it says "zsh: command not found: flutter"
Is this because I'm no longer using bin (or bash), and now using zsh?

Can someone tell me what I can do to solve this issue? Im not very good at  entering Terminal commands, so what exactly would I type to fix this issue? (I'm a beginner)

When I was entering vim bash_profile in the Terminal, I entered the following as the Export Path:

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/raymondfontaine/Developer/flutter/bin"

Comment: So, would this mean that I would downgrade back to Mojave OS? Would that correct the issue?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and it occurred after switching from bash to zsh. A far as I know, you have three different options.

1. Switch your Terminal back from zsh to bash by typing `chsh -s /bin/bash` and restart your Terminal. Note: You can always switch back to zsh by typing `chsh -s /bin/zsh` and restarting your Terminal.
2. You can tell zsh to use the paths specified in your bash_profile file by typing `source ~/.bash_profile` into your Terminal. Note: You have to do this every time you open a new Terminal.
3. The two options above are probably not "Best Practice". The best solution would be to set environment variables for zsh as suggested by the flutter Tutorial: [Update your Path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path).
   In your case you have to type `nano $HOME/.zshrc` into your Terminal enter `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/raymondfontaine/Developer/flutter/bin"` there, save the file and restart the Terminal. After that `flutter doctor -v` should run as usual.

Also the emulators in Android Studio should load again. But if you still cannot start them via the Dropdown, try opening them via `Tools > AVD Manager`. This worked for me while they were not visible in the Dropdown Menu.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this detailed answer